# Implementing Tracker to Persist OCR Results for Cars in Video Frames

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I have a Python function, detect_and_draw_cars used in a loop and given frames from a video, which utilizes YOLO to identify and draw bounding boxes around cars in each frame of a video. Additionally, the function performs OCR on the regions of interest (if found) within these bounding boxes to extract the license plates (function box4).

To optimize the OCR processing, I am looking to implement an OpenCV tracker that can track the center of the cars over multiple frames. The goal is to update the OCR results only once every 60 frames or so for each car, as the shape and orientation of the cars change gradually over time i'm thinking of tracking images by their center.

```py
if tracked_cars[car_id]["frames_since_last_ocr"] == 60:
   car_roi = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
   ocr_result = box4(car_roi)
```

i grasp the idea of an openCV tracker but in this context where there are a lot of different trackers i hit a roadblock. I am seeking guidance on how to integrate an OpenCV tracker that efficiently tracks the center of the cars across frames, ensuring that OCR results are updated only once every 60 frames for each car. Any code snippets, suggestions, or examples would be highly appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the existing code before implementing trackers :

```py
def detect_and_draw_cars(image):
    car_images, car_coordinates = yolo_predire(image)
    for i, (x1, y1, x2, y2) in enumerate(car_coordinates):
        result=[]

        cv2.rectangle(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        car_roi = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]

        result = box4(car_roi)
        if result:
          print(result)
          ocr_text = f"{result[0][-2]} - {(result[0][-1]*100):.2f}%"
          text_size, _ = cv2.getTextSize(ocr_text, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 1)
          cv2.rectangle(image, (x1, y1 - text_size[1] - 10), (x1 + text_size[0] + 10, y1), (255, 255, 255), -1)
          cv2.putText(image, ocr_text, (x1, y1 - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 0, 0), 3)

    return image
```

i tried implementing openCV trackers for multiple objects in video frames but couldn't get it to work in a loop